# logback-spring.xml is not working with spring boot 1.4.2

Tags: spring-boot

I am using logback 1.1.8 with spring boot 1.4.2 as soon as I change the name of logback.xml to logback-spring.xml application stops logging. And when I use logback.xml, I cannot use the springProfiles tags.

> 15:55:23,459 |-ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@153:46 - no applicable
>   action for [appender-ref], current ElementPath  is
>   [[configuration][springProfile][root][appender-ref]] 15:55:23,459
>   |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@154:46 - no
>   applicable action for [appender-ref], current ElementPath  is
>   [[configuration][springProfile][root][appender-ref]] 15:55:23,460
>   |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@158:36 - no
>   applicable action for [springProfile], current ElementPath  is
>   [[configuration][springProfile]]

Please, suggest if this issue is faced by anyone?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour, have a look around, and read through the help center, in particular How do I ask a good question? and What topics can I ask about here? From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." You also must provide your question as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot tries to load the logback.xml from classpath, In my case, though I have replaced logback.xml with logback-spring.xml it was reading logback.xml, on debugging found that one of the libraries in classpath is providing the logback.xml causing this issue

Comment: So how did you resolve the issue? Did you remove the complete dependency or is there a way to configure spring to use a specific logback config file?

Comment: In my case, it was an internal library so I had to fix its pom to not include logback.xml in final artifact after this spring was able to pull the correct one